# Can the circle be characterized by the following property?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

In the Euclidean plane, is the circle the only simple closed curve that has an axis of symmetry in every 
direction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A slightly different argument is as follows. Choose two symmetries $\sigma,\tau$
with axes
intersecting at a point $P$ and forming an angle of $2\pi \lambda$ with $\lambda$ irrational.
The composition $\rho=\sigma\circ \tau$ is then a rotation of infinite order generating
a dense subgroup of the group of all rotations centered at $P$.
Any closed subset left invariant under $\rho$ is thus a union of concentric circles centered at $P$. A simple closed curve invariant under $\rho$ is thus such a circle.

Answer (score 31):

If a figure had an axis of symmetry in three non-parallel
but non-concurrent axes, then composing these suitably would
give a translative symmetry, which is impossible if the figure
is bounded. So all the axes of symmetry of your putative curve
are concurrent through a point $O$ which we shall call a centre.
Then all rotations about the centre $O$ are symmetries. The only
simple closed curves with this property are circles centred at $O$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers which I was not quite able to figure out 
for myself.
